# Different electron .html files in one

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, w2ui

I need to somehow import a lot of html pages into one in electron(im using w2ui layout).

I have tried:

```
<iframe src="../map/index.html"></iframe>
```

but it does not work:

```
<script>require('./index.js');</script>
```

> (Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at index.html:15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to include the HTML from multiple files into one page.

You can do this by using jQuery
`$('#elementToLoadHtmlInTo').load('url/pathToFile')`

you could also try using the fs module in nodejs to load the content from your files and then add it to your file.

Comment: can i use jquery with w2u somehow?

Comment: I don't see any reason you can't

Comment: But how do i use it with jquery then? This is how i change the main field: w2ui['layout'].content('main', "HTML");

Comment: I haven't used w2ui before but it does say it is compatible with jQuery and was made with jQuery in mind.

Comment: From what I understand you should be able to do your w2ui stuff then after it load the html with jQuery and query it with the layout your using with w2ui